# Casting string to date in BigQuery - year only string produces error

Tags: sql, date, google-bigquery

I'm trying to change a string column into a date format in a BigQuery select statement. Most of the data appeared to be in the correct format of '2021-10-22' however when I run
`SELECT MIN(CAST(add_timestamp AS date)) AS date_added`
I get the error **Invalid date string "1999"**

One of the dates is obviously inputted as simply "1999". Is there a way I make this into a date (e.g. 1999-01-01) in the select statement?

Answer (score 0):

If you are positive the only improper date format will be a 4 digit year you could do the following:

```
select cast(if(length(date_added)<=4,concat(date_added,'-01-01'),date_added) as date)
from sample_data
```

This will not work for scenarios outside of that.  You may also want to take a look at the `SAFE` condition, and execute a `SAFE_CAST`.  In that case you would return a `NULL` record.  That way your query will always execute and not take in bad date values.